# Jetpack Compose - how do you do minEms in a Text component?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have an existing TextView with minEms set to 2

I want to convert the TextView to a Compose Text component

Is there an equivalent for minEms in Compose?

Answer (score 0):

I share you this code, I hope it help you.

`fontSize = 10.em` is the Key.

```
Text(
    text = "How to use em",
    style = TextStyle.Default.copy(fontSize = 10.em)
)
```